# How can I get the most recent date using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database, greatest-n-per-group

How can I get the most recent date using MySQL? I tried max but I did not get the result that I want. My table looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| Name    | idStore | Name                  | idItem | date       | price   |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-22 | 0.98000 |
| walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.98000 |
| walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.98000 |
| walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-11-22 | 0.98000 |
| walmart |       1 | Honeycrisp Apples     |      2 | 2011-10-22 | 1.98000 |
| walmart |       1 | Sonya Apples          |      3 | 2011-10-22 | 2.88000 |
| walmart |       1 | Gold Delicious Apples |      4 | 2011-10-22 | 0.98000 |
| walmart |       1 | Sweet Tango Apples    |      5 | 2011-10-22 | 2.48000 |
| walmart |       1 | Granny Smith Apples   |      6 | 2011-10-22 | 1.28000 |
| walmart |       1 | Fugi Apples           |      7 | 2011-10-22 | 1.38000 |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
```

I want to get this table:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| Name    | idStore | Name                  | idItem | date       | price   |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-11-22 | 0.98000 |
| walmart |       1 | Honeycrisp Apples     |      2 | 2011-10-22 | 1.98000 |
| walmart |       1 | Sonya Apples          |      3 | 2011-10-22 | 2.88000 |
| walmart |       1 | Gold Delicious Apples |      4 | 2011-10-22 | 0.98000 |
| walmart |       1 | Sweet Tango Apples    |      5 | 2011-10-22 | 2.48000 |
| walmart |       1 | Granny Smith Apples   |      6 | 2011-10-22 | 1.28000 |
| walmart |       1 | Fugi Apples           |      7 | 2011-10-22 | 1.38000 |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
```

I am having hard time figuring this out. Thanks!

Comment: You're not the only one that has a hard time figuring this out. I suggest you elaborate by giving some code you've tried to get the result, so we can see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Online Example Query

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118881/how-can-i-get-the-most-resent-date-using-mysql

```
SELECT NameStore, idStore, Name, idItem, max(date) AS date, price
FROM tablename
GROUP by NameStore, idStore, Name, idItem, price
ORDER BY date DESC, idItem ASC
```

Comment: Note : this won't work if he wants really only the most recent date, and the price that applied on that date, regardless of what other prices might have applied on elder dates.

Answer (score 3):

You can use group by:

```
select NameStore, idStore, Name, idItem, max(date) date, price
from table
group by NameStore, idStore, Name, idItem, price
```

Answer (score 1):

See [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

```
SELECT yt1.*
FROM yourtable yt1
LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable yt2 ON (yt1.idItem = yt2.idItem AND yt1.date < yt2.date)
WHERE yt2.idItem IS NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

put this at the end `ORDER BY date DESC`

So make it look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Using `DISTINCT(Name)` or `GROUP BY Name` in the SQL sentence above, would make one item pop up only once.

Comment: But he also want to only see one line per idItem. Hint: GROUP BY?

Comment: And then see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341737/mysql-changing-the-query-to-be-distinct-on-just-1-column) for distinct values

Comment: -1 the order by is not what he needs; this will still keep the duplicate dates in there.

Comment: "How can I get the most recent date using MySQL?" is the Question, sorry for answering it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) clause like this:

```
SELECT Name, idStore, Name, idItem, date, price 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY idItem 
ORDER BY date DESC, idItem DESC;
```

Change the order direction using DESC or ASC. You can learn more about this reading the documentation.